# Boot From USB Stick

Tags: windows, usb, usb-flash-drive, filesystems, fat32

I formatted a 16 GB USB Stick today so I could boot from it and that works great.  The problem I have is it won't let me copy a 7GB Ghost image over to USB, it says there isn't enough space.  When I look Windows shows there is 14GB available.  Can anyone give me some insight into this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably have formatted the USB stick to FAT32 filesystem which does not support filesizes in excess of 4GB. Try reformatting it as NTFS.

Comment: Ah.  I sure did.  I am not sure if NTFS will work but I will give it a shot.

Comment: So apparently NTFS is not a bootable format.  Do you know of any ways around this issue?

Comment: @Nathan NTFS is a bootable format. The image probably doeesn't have the correct boot records. Unfortunately I haven't tried what you're trying to do, perhaps these links would help? : http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/30106-35-making-ghost-recovery-disk-bootable http://forum.notebookreview.com/hardware-components-aftermarket-upgrades/104293-how-make-external-usb-hard-drive-bootable-using-ghost-v10.html

You probably want to create 2 partitions, 1 small (FAT/32)to carry the boot records, and the other larger to store the ghost image.

Comment: Basically what I am trying to do is make a bootable USB stick which contains the Norton Ghost boot software and then move the image onto the same USB stick so I can boot and image from the same device.  Does this help at all?

Comment: @Nathan yes, that's what you should try to do. If all goes well, it should work swell

Comment: I formatted the usb stick to NTFS using DISKPART and when it goes to boot it says it can't find BOOTMGR?  Do you know how to fix this?  I looked through what you posted and I can't get any of it to work.

Comment: @Nathan Sorry I'm not sure how to proceed further. Let me try to search for something else.

Answer (score 0):

While using NTFS instead of FAT32 may work, you can also get it to work with FAT32. You have to split the large image file (`install.wim`) into pieces of 4 GB. You can do it with the following command (where `D:` contains your mounted .ISO file and `E:` is your USB stick):

```
DISM /Split-Image /ImageFile:D:\sources\install.wim /SWMFile:E:\sources\install.swm /FileSize:4096
```

You can read more about the creation of a Windows boot stick in my answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/1627333/1077440).