# How do I install Windows 10 from USB to a UEFI Secure Boot Machine

Tags: windows-10, uefi, secure-boot

With a new bare Machine how do I install Windows 10 from a USB stick and install it with secure boot and EFI turned on?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, at least not from the linked question, since this question asks for how to do it bootable *without disabling secure boot*, I had a similar problem, and the accepted answer did the trick for me, while Windows USB Download tool didn't! So I upvoted both the question and the answer.

Comment: The procedure is the same because there isn't anything special you have to do.

Comment: I needed to use Microsoft's "mediacreationtool.exe" to download and install directly to the USB. I've found that you can't download to an ISO and then use the "Windows 7 USB DVD Download Tool" to create a secure boot compatible USB.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. First make sure your bios has secure boot turned on.
2. Next, build your USB stick with Fat32
3. Then install normally.

The 11 steps for manually preparing / building a USB Disk to be a bootable Win 10 Install. 
This bootable USB stick will work for both older BIOS installs as well as the newer UEFI installs.

1. Diskpart (Run from a CMD prompt)
2. List Disk
3. Select Disk # (Where # is the number of your USB disk)
4. Clean (removes any partitions on the USB disk, including any hidden sectors)
5. Create Partition Primary (Creates a new primary partition with default parameters)
6. Select Partition 1 (Focus on the newly created partition)
7. Active (Sets the selected partition to an active valid system partition state)
8. Format FS=fat32 quick (Formats the partition with the FAT32 file system. FAT32 is needed instead of NTFS so that it can load under the secure boot UEFI BIOS.)
9. Assign (Assigns the USB drive a drive letter)
10. Exit
11. Copy all the files from the Windows 10 isO to the USB Stick.

For more details see my blog post at: http://mythoughtsonit.com/2014/05/installing-windows-8-1-from-usb-to-a-uefi-secure-boot-machine/

Comment: The steps above are still needed with the ISO if you are doing a fresh install from a usb stick. Or burn the ISO to DVDs.

Comment: Unfortunately, install.wim is 4,469,518,898 bytes in September 2018, which is too large for a single file on FAT32. This approach no longer works for recent versions of Windows 10.

Comment: kind-a tedious, what I did is convert the wim to esd to compress it, build iso from said esd, then use this method or the rufus method.

Comment: @bart You can split the `install.wim` into pieces. See my answer [below](https://superuser.com/a/1627333/1077440).

Answer (score 7):

FYI..  Best tool I have seen for Windows for creating a USB Boot Disk from ISO is - Rufus: https://rufus.akeo.ie/ and works great.  There are some helpful USB tools in LINUX Mint - but, that is out-of-scope here.  ;)

[image: Rufus]

**Overview from the Site:**

Rufus is a utility that helps format and create bootable USB flash drives, such as USB keys/pendrives, memory sticks, etc.

It can be especially useful for cases where:

- you need to create USB installation media from bootable ISOs (Windows, Linux, UEFI, etc.)
- you need to work on a system that doesn't have an OS installed
- you need to flash a BIOS or other firmware from DOS
- you want to run a low-level utility

Despite its small size, Rufus provides everything you need!

Comment: Note that Rufus doesn't appear to support installing to a machine with secure boot enabled (as the OP asked for), but you can install with secure boot disabled, and then re-enable secure boot after installation is complete.

Comment: I've read that if you install with secure boot disabled that you will have to reinstall. Does it depend on the operating system?

Comment: As of Rufus 3.17, Rufus __does__ support installing Windows on a machine with Secure Boot enabled.

Answer (score 7):

The following method works without external tools and it works with image files that are larger than 4 GB. Basically, you need a USB drive with a FAT32 file system<sup>1</sup> and an active partition. You can use the following **PowerShell** commands to prepare your USB drive:

1. Use `Get-Disk` to identify your USB drive (look for the `Friendly Name` and `Total Size` columns, for example, and then note the `Number` of your USB drive).
2. Prepare your USB drive with the following pipeline (note that this will erase your entire USB drive):

   ```
   Clear-Disk -Number <USE_NUMBER_FROM_STEP_ONE> -RemoveData -RemoveOEM -Confirm:$false -PassThru | New-Partition -UseMaximumSize -AssignDriveLetter -IsActive | Format-Volume -FileSystem FAT32
   ```

After that, your USB drive is ready to receive the files of the Windows image. Copy all image files to the USB drive, except the `install.wim` file, if it exceeds 4 GB (FAT32 cannot handle files larger than 4 GB)<sup>2</sup>:

```
Copy-Item -Recurse -Path D:\* -Destination E:\ -Exclude install.wim
```

If your *install* file is larger than 4 GB (which is most probably the case nowadays), split it into pieces with the following command<sup>2</sup>:

```
DISM /Split-Image /ImageFile:D:\sources\install.wim /SWMFile:E:\sources\install.swm /FileSize:4096
```

This will create multiple `install.swm` files (`install.swm`, `install2.swm`, etc.) depending on the size of the source file.

After that, your USB drive is ready to serve as both, a legacy boot stick or a UEFI boot stick even with *Secure Boot* enabled.

---

<sup>1</sup> FAT32 is compatible with more systems than NTFS. Therefore, you are more flexible when using this older format.

<sup>2</sup> Where `D:` contains your mounted .ISO file and `E:` is your USB drive

Comment: This is a good answer, updating the accepted answer to use PowerShell as well as building on Microsoft's advice of using`Dism /split-image`: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/install-windows-from-a-usb-flash-drive?view=windows-11#if-your-windows-image-is-larger-than-4gb