# How to boot from USB on a System 76 Gazelle?

Tags: windows-10, boot, usb, ubuntu-16.04

How can configure my System76 Gazelle laptop to boot from a USB drive?

[image]

I've restarted and tried F2 and F7 but I can't seem to figure out a way to see my USB drive.

My USB drive is plugged on and turned on. And it has a Windows 10 ISO on it.  My goal is to install Windows 10 Pro on my Gazelle laptop (or perhaps dual boot Ubuntu / Windows but I'll save that for another question).

Below are photos from my Setup Utility that I see when I F2 (or F7 and choose setup).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

And this is what I see when I F7 after restart:
[image]

**Update**
I now see the bootable USB drive (my original issue was that the drive was NOT bootable). I created it with Etcher.  Now when I select that drive, brief flash and then the same menu is displayed with the same choices.

https://photos.app.goo.gl/9VU8pHkvzBP7ZEyf8

**Update #2**
My second attempt at making a bootable USB was using [WoeUsb](https://www.fossmint.com/woeusb-create-bootable-windows-usb-sticks-from-linux/).  That produced a bootable USB that worked.
[image]

Comment: The usb drive must be bootable before it will show up in the list, is it bootable? How was the usb drive created?

Comment: No, I think that is my issue.  I haven't installed an OS since the time CDs!  Just created a bootable one.    Going to try it now.

Comment: It appears your system is UEFI-only. You need to create a UEFI-bootable installation medium. It’ll be a lot easier with a USB flash drive.

Comment: Yes, I was able to create one using WoeUSB. I tried creating one with Etchio, which completed w/ no errors and was visible as an option but I could not boot from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting an ISO on a USB stick will not make the USB stick bootable.  That's your first problem.

You'll need to make a USB installer disk, and there are several ways to do so.  An answer on this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/962132/how-do-i-install-windows-10-from-usb-to-a-uefi-secure-boot-machine) recommends [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/).  Microsoft [makes a tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool) to take your Windows ISO and make a bootable drive.

After you make a bootable USB stick, then you may need to worry about SecureBoot.  [HowToGeek has an article](https://www.howtogeek.com/175641/how-to-boot-and-install-linux-on-a-uefi-pc-with-secure-boot/) walking you through booting USB with SecureBoot enabled.

From the article:

> New Windows PCs come with UEFI firmware and Secure Boot enabled.
>   Secure Boot prevents operating systems from booting unless they’re
>   signed by a key loaded into UEFI — out of the box, only
>   Microsoft-signed software can boot.
>
> Microsoft mandates that PC vendors allow users to disable Secure Boot,
>   so you can disable Secure Boot or add your own custom key to get
>   around this limitation. Secure Boot can’t be disabled on ARM devices
>   running Windows RT.
>
> **How Secure Boot Works**
>
> RELATED: How Secure Boot Works on Windows 8 and 10, and What It Means
>   for Linux
>
> PCs that come with Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 include UEFI firmware
>   instead of the traditional BIOS. By default, the machine’s UEFI
>   firmware will only boot boot loaders signed by a key embedded in the
>   UEFI firmware. This feature is known as “Secure Boot” or “Trusted
>   Boot.” On traditional PCs without this security feature, a rootkit
>   could install itself and become the boot loader. The computer’s BIOS
>   would then load the rootkit at boot time, which would boot and load
>   Windows, hiding itself from the operating system and embedding itself
>   at a deep level.
>
> Secure Boot blocks this — the computer will only boot trusted
>   software, so malicious boot loaders won’t be able to infect the
>   system.
>
> On an Intel x86 PC (not ARM PCs), you have control over Secure Boot.
>   You can choose to disable it or even add your own signing key.
>   Organizations could use their own keys to ensure only approved Linux
>   operating systems could boot, for example.
>
> **Options for Installing Linux**
>
> You have several options for installing Linux on a PC with Secure
>   Boot:
>
> Choose a Linux Distribution That Supports Secure Boot: Modern versions of 
>   Ubuntu — starting with Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS and 12.10 — will
>   boot and install normally on most PCs with Secure Boot enabled. This
>   is because Ubuntu’s first-stage EFI boot loader is signed by
>   Microsoft. However, a Ubuntu developer notes that Ubuntu’s boot loader
>   isn’t signed with a key that’s required by Microsoft’s certification
>   process, but simply a key Microsoft says is “recommended.” This means
>   that Ubuntu may not boot on all UEFI PCs. Users may have to disable
>   Secure Boot to to use Ubuntu on some PCs.
>       Disable Secure Boot: Secure Boot can be disabled, which will exchange its security benefits for the ability to have your PC boot
>   anything, just as older PCs with the traditional BIOS do. This is also
>   necessary if you want to install an older version of Windows that
>   wasn’t developed with Secure Boot in mind, such as Windows 7.
>       Add a Signing Key to the UEFI Firmware: Some Linux distributions may sign their boot loaders with their own key, which you can add to
>   your UEFI firmware. This doesn’t seem to be a common at the moment.
>
> You should check to see which process your Linux distribution of
>   choice recommends. If you need to boot an older Linux distribution
>   that doesn’t provide any information about this, you’ll just need to
>   disable Secure Boot.
>
> You should be able to install current versions of Ubuntu — either the
>   LTS release or the latest release — without any trouble on most new
>   PCs. See the last section for instructions on booting from a removable
>   device.